# What does .WW stand for in Microsoft installer files/folders?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, windows-installer, setup, acronym

What does ww stand for in terms of microsoft installers? At the root of their office product for example, there are folders like proplus.ww and proplus.en-us each of which contain various .exe and .msi files. But It looks like the .ww file contains the more important .msi file. (For example, If I am deploying software with SCCM, the .WW file/folder is the one I need to choose)

**Edit:**
Research effort: I have tried googling it, and I have yet to find any sort of official answer from Microsoft or general consensus.

The answer provided to this question seems to make the most sense, and likely the actual answer.

Comment: What does your research effort say?

Comment: @Moab I have tried googling it, and I can not for the life of me get an answer, maybe I'm not searching the write keywords.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can't find anything on it either. I searched http://www.file-extensions.org but it didn't have a ww extension in their database.

Comment: Because it's not a _file_ extension...

Comment: Edit your question to include your research effort please, so I can up vote.

Comment: @Moab sorry about that, I have added an edit including that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `proplus.en-us`, it seems the format is `<product>.<locale>`. So `proplus.ww` is likely to mean "**w**orld**w**ide" (locale-neutral) – files that are installed no matter which language is chosen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Worldwide is what I was thinking, but was very unsure. Well thought out explained answer.